# Select in many to many relations in MySQL with multiple conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, many-to-many

Let's imagine we have a small MySQL database:

**Women:**

- id_woman
- name
- surname

**women_shoes:**

- id_woman (FK)
- id_shoe (FK)

**Shoes:**

- id_shoe
- name

**woman_handbags:**

- id_woman (FK)
- id_handbag (FK)

**Handbags:**

- id_handbag
- name

There are 2 relations many-to-many. What I want to get from such DB is: select all women which have shoes: nike, puma, mango and handbags: versace. I am interested in women who have every presented pair of shoes and every handbag. I know names of stuff and I want to find out the names.

Comment: @JohnRuddell
I tried something similar to your select below, but instead of IN I had pair of brackets with ORs inside it. Anyway, it still doesn't give me results I want.

Comment: I updated the query. you can't do OR as that is the same thing as using an IN() use AND. look at my query now

Comment: @TheOpti, could you provide some sample data for these tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this? if i understand your question correctly.

```
SELECT 
    r.* 
FROM recipe r
JOIN recipe_ingredients ri ON ri.id_recipe = r.id_recipe
JOIN ingredients i ON i.id_ingredient = ri.id_ingredient
JOIN recipes_tags rt ON rt.id_recipe = r.id_recipe
JOIN tags t ON t.id_tag = rt.id_tag
WHERE i.name = 'ziemniaki' 
   OR i.name = 'cebula'
  AND t.tag = "tani" 
   OR t.tag = "łatwy"
GROUP BY r.id_recipe
HAVING COUNT(r.id_recipe) > 3 -- all 4 of the criteria have been met
;
```

see working [FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ad5c0/23) for clarification

Basically what this does is it returns a row when one of the four criteria is met. along with that it also will only return recipes that have at least one of the ingredients and at least one of the tags. so when 4 (or more) rows are returned then the criteria is met for a recipe with the requested params

Comment: Your select will give me women who have versace but ONE of the items mentioned in 'IN' clause. I want to get women who have ALL these items and that's the biggest problem for me...

Comment: then just remove the IN() and do each one separate with an AND clause... updated my answer with the change

Comment: I also tried something like this select. The problem is I can't compare one raw with all these ANDs. It's simply impossible for one raw to have 3 different values.

Comment: ok. can you post some of the data then so I can see what you need? because im flying blind here. if a woman has those three linked then it should work

Comment: @TheOpti try it again with LEFT JOINS (they don't filter)

Comment: Unfortunately your query doesn't work - there are no rows returned. It seems that it's still caused by ANDs.

Comment: that is most likely because you have an un-normalized database. if you send me some data or post some or something then I can solve it for you quickly. but without knowing how you have it set up theres not much we can do.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/byzcZtv.png

Here you can see my DB EER diagram. I want to select recipes which have tags 'X' and 'y' and include ingredients: 'a' and 'b'.

http://pastebin.com/4XRkXXKb

And here you have my database. I want to find a recipe which has ingredients: 'cebula' and 'ziemniaki' and has tags: 'tani', 'łatwy'.

Comment: @TheOpti ok with the information you provided I updated my query with a working copy to pull out data on the specific requirements. if you need to add more to the query let me know. that should work just fine as is though :)

Answer (score 1):

Since the 2nd criteria only has 1 handbag you don't really need to select from a subquery but I figured it might change to multiple handbags.

```
SELECT
    w.*
FROM women w 
JOIN 
(
    SELECT
        id_woman
    FROM woman_shoes ws 
    JOIN shoes s ON ws.id_shoe = s.id_shoe
    WHERE s.name IN ('puma','nike','mango')
    GROUP BY id_woman
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
) has_shoes hs ON hs.id_woman = w.id_woman
JOIN 
(
    SELECT
        id_woman
    FROM woman_handbags wh 
    JOIN handbags h ON wh.id_handbag = h.id_handbag
    WHERE h.name IN ('versace')
    GROUP BY id_woman
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
) has_handbag hb ON hb.id_woman = w.id_woman
```

Answer (score 0):

A try to do something like that - but i have problem...

i want to make bibliography records - i have a table where i store the datas of the selected articles (bibl_1983) - and i have tables where i store the themes (keywords) and names (persons mentioned in the article) - i try to convert a real bibliography into online searchable something - so i want to keep the original data system - to be compatible with the original printed one...

i could easily do if i want to show only one thing - for example the keywords or the persons

Tables are:

bibl_1983:
`pub_id`,
`author`,
`title`,
`periodical`,
`date`,
`volume`,
`issue`,
`page`,
`illustration`,
`annotation`

contable_name:
`contname_id`,
`name_id2`,
`pub_id4`

namespace:
`name_id`,
`name`

contable_subject:
`cont_id`,
`sub_id2`,
`pub_id3`

subject:
`sub_id`,
`subject`

```
SELECT bibl_1983.pub_id, group_concat(subject.subject 
ORDER BY subject.subject ASC) AS subject
FROM bibl_1983, subject, contable_subject 
WHERE ((bibl_1983.pub_id=contable_subject.pub_id3) AND 
(subject.sub_id=contable_subject.sub_id2))
GROUP BY bibl_1983.pub_id
```

it is works fine, and great and this is too:

```
SELECT bibl_1983.pub_id, group_concat(namespace.name 
ORDER BY namespace.name ASC) AS name
FROM bibl_1983, namespace, contable_name 
WHERE ((bibl_1983.pub_id=contable_name.pub_id4) AND
 (namespace.name_id=contable_name.name_id2))
GROUP BY bibl_1983.pub_id
```

But i couldnt find out, how can i show the two things in the same time, in the same way, on the same page.

It is two different many to many connections.

What i want to show:
article datas + keywords + persons in one query (or view).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33226143)